# What are the colour codes of all colors?

Tags: ios, drawquest

I need to find out the rgb color codes of all the colors in DrawQuest. Sorry if this is off-topic, but I need an answer. I cannot find most of the colors in the net.

EDIT: I am using the colors in my sprites that I'm making for a sample RPG game. I want the colors as a guide palette so I don't have to waste too much time selecting colors for them. I have tried eye dropping, but the color circles have a wide number of color codes(the total space), and averaging didn't do me any good.

```
  I'm wanting to find a solid color code index. Don't need to send me the whole list, excluding colors that can be found on the net like slate, black, white, snow grey, etc.
```

Comment: [This image](http://sydlingflyer.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/colourss3.jpg) appears to show the entire palette, I was going to try and automatically sample the colours but I'm coming up short - worst comes to the worst you could manually eye drop them in photoshop

Comment: What would you like to use them for?